# Roots of unity in rings of algebraic integers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Context: Let $ K $ be an algebraic number field. Let $ O_K $ be the ring of integers of $ K $. Let $ O_K^\times $ denote the group of units of $ O_K $. By Dirichlet's unit theorem, $ O_K^\times $ is always a finitely generated abelian group. The torsion subgroup of $ O_K^\times $ is always a finite cyclic group and is exactly all the roots of unity that are in $ K $.

Question 1: Are there any well known sufficient conditions for $ O_K^\times $ to have free rank $ 0 $ (in other words, conditions implying $ O_K^\times $ finite) (Edit: By Dirichlet's unit theorem $ O_K^\times $ is finite if and only if $ K=\mathbb{Q} $ or $ K $ is an imaginary quadratic field, see comment from Lukas Heger)

Question 2: Are there any well known formulas for determining the largest $ d $ for which the root of unity $ \zeta_d $ exists in $ K $? (in other words, finding the order of $ Tor(O_K^\times) $)

Edit (just fleshing out the comment from Bart Michels): Since roots of unity are algebraic integers then all the roots of unity in an algebraic number field $ K $ are also in $ O_K $. Thus the $ w_K $ appearing in the class number formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_formula denotes both the number of roots of unity in $ K $ and the number of roots of unity in $ O_K $.

Comment: The group of units is finite exactly for $\Bbb Q$ and imaginary quadratic fields

Comment: @LukasHeger Oh great! Does that follow easily from Dirichlet's unit theorem or something like that?

Comment: Yes, exactly it follows from Dirichlet's unit theorem

Comment: Ok I'll edit the question to reflect that, thanks

Comment: For question 2, I would look at the degree of $K$ – if there is a primitice $d$-th root, then $\varphi(d) \mid [K:\mathbb{Q}]$, its real embeddings (if $K$ has any, then the torsion subgroup is $\pm 1$), and the ramification (if there is a primitive $p$-th root of unity, then $K$ is “very” ramified at $p$ – I think that, for instance, $p^{[K:\mathbb{Q}](p-2)/(p-1)}$ divides the discriminant of $K$).

Comment: The class number formula involves the size of the torsion group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w$ be the number of roots of unity in $K$, so $w$ is even. If $p$ is a prime factor of $w$ then $\mathbf Q(\zeta_p) \subset K$. Since $(p) = (1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}$ in $\mathbf Z[\zeta_p]$, every prime $\mathfrak p$ over $p$ in $K$ ramifies when $p > 2$. Hence when a prime $\mathfrak p$ in $K$ is unramified and $\mathfrak p$ doesn't lie over $2$, $\mathfrak p \nmid (w)$. Then $x^w - 1 \bmod \mathfrak p$ is separable and splits completely, so $w  \mid ({\rm N}(\mathfrak p)-1)$.

There is a converse result: if $d  \mid ({\rm N}(\mathfrak p)-1)$ for all but finitely many unramified $\mathfrak p$, then $d \mid w$, so $w$ is the gcd of the integers ${\rm N}(\mathfrak p)-1$ as $\mathfrak p$ runs over any set of all but finitely many unramified primes in $K$.
This may not look like a practical way of computing $w$, but if you can compute norms of prime ideals in $K$ then you can look  at a large finite set of such numbers ${\rm N}(\mathfrak p) - 1$ to make a plausible guess at the gcd of all such numbers (with $\mathfrak p$ unramified and not lying over $2$) in order to guess a value for $w$.

**Example**. Take $K = \mathbf Q(i)$, for which $w = 4$. When $(\pi)$ is a prime in $\mathbf Q(i)$ other than $(1+i)$ then ${\rm N}(\pi)-1$ is divisible by $4$, either by a direct calculation (since ${\rm N}(\pi)$ is a prime that's $1 \bmod 4$ or is $p^2$ where $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$) or because $\mathbf Z[i]/(\pi)$ is a field containing a primitive $4$th root of unity.
If $(\pi)$ runs over all but finitely many primes in $\mathbf Q(i)$ other than $(1+i)$ then it can be proved that the numbers ${\rm N}(\pi)-1$ have gcd $4$. This generalizes the fact that if $m \geq 2$ then and $p$ runs over all but finitely many primes that are $1 \bmod m$, then the numbers $p-1$ have gcd $m$ (proved by Dirichlet's theorem).

Comment: $(p) = ((1-\zeta_p))^{p-1} = ((1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}) \implies (1-\zeta_p)^{p-1} \times (1+\zeta^*_p)^{p-1} \in ((1-\zeta_p)^{p-1})$ $ \implies i^{p-1} 2^{p-1} sin^{p-1}(2 \pi/p) \in ((1-\zeta_p)^{p-1})$. But i am not sure what multiple of $p$ is actually equal to $i ^{p-1} 2^{p-1} sin(2 \pi/p)$. Overall  for $ (p) = ((1-\zeta_p))^{p-1} = ((1-\zeta_p)^{p-1})$ there must be factorization of $p$ in terms $(1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}$ and a unit. Can you clarify the factorization by explicitly giving a unit which multiplies with $(1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}$ and gives $p$ ?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_w]/(p) = \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_w]$ which is a finite field of order $p^w -1$ and $w$ divides $p^w - 1 = N(p) - 1$. Is this a more straight forward argument to prove $w$ divides $N(p)-1$? I think what you are telling is a more general result. Can you please clarify ?

Comment: When $\mathfrak p | (p)$, $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p$ has characterisic $p$, so when $p \nmid w$ the polynomial $x^w - 1$ has distinct roots in characteristic $p$. When $\mathbf Q(\zeta_w) \subset K$, the polynomial $x^w - 1$ has $w$ roots in $\mathcal O_K$ and thus $w$ distinct roots in $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p$ if $p \nmid w$. Hence the group $(\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p)^\times$ has a subgroup of order $w$, so $w \mid ({\rm N}(\mathfrak p)-1)$.

Comment: @Balajisb  Your 2nd comment has an error at the start: the ring $\mathbf Z[\zeta_w]/(p)$ has characteristic $p$ but it is *not* usually a field because $(p)$ need not be a prime ideal in $\mathbf Z[\zeta_w]$, e.g., whenever $p \equiv 1 \bmod w$ (think about $w = 4$)

Comment: @Balajisb  That $(p) = (1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}$ as ideals in $\mathbf Z[\zeta_p]$ is discussed in lots of books on algebraic number theory (see chapters on cyclotomic fields). An explicit unit factor is $p/(1-\zeta_p)^{p-1}$, which admittedly is perhaps not a satisfying answer, but look at how algebraic number theory books talk about cyclotomic fields to see more details on this topic.

Comment: For seeing $x^w - 1$ has distinct roots in $O_K/\mathcal{p}$, we can go to an extension such that finite field of order $p^w-1$ is contained and since in this finite field we have distinct roots for the equation $x^w - 1$, we must have distinct roots in  $O_K/\mathcal{p}$ also. This is an argument i have. Is there a more direct way of seeing this ?

Comment: Further what if $\zeta_w^i = \zeta_w^j$ in $O_K/p$ ? in which case in an extension we may have distinct roots but roots in $O_K$ collapses after congruence w.r.t prime ideal $p$.

Comment: @Balajisb Avoid using $\mathcal O_K/(p)$ all the time: it may not be a field, such as $\mathbf Z[i]/(5)$. So it doesn't make sense to "go to an extension" containing some finite field when you start in a finite ring that is not a field. To be in a residue field of characteristic $p$, use $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p$ where $\mathfrak p \mid (p)$. When $f(x)$ splits completely in $\mathcal O_K[x]$, its reduction mod $\mathfrak p$ splits completely in $(\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p)[x]$. And if $f(x) \bmod \mathfrak p$ is separable then its roots there are distinct, like $x^w-1$ when $p \nmid w$.

Comment: By $O_K/p$ i was refering to $O_K/\mathfrak{p}$. I went to an extension containing finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^w}$ because $(p) \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$. I did not type it properly. Thanks for the explanation Cheers !

Comment: I went to an extension containing finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^w}$ to prove the separability of $f(x) \mod \mathfrak{p}$ which was not clear.

Comment: Further Isnt $O_K/\mathfrak{p}$ isomorphic to a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ ? This is because $|O_K/\mathfrak{p}|  = N(\mathfrak{p})< \infty$ i.e., finite and has characteristic $p$.